# Unable to access csv.dictreader object

Tags: python, csv

For a CSV file:

- a,b,c,d
- 1,2,3,4
- 5,6,7,8
- 9,10,11,12

While the code below works fine to output the rows of the CSV:

```
import csv
import sys

database = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], mode='r') as csv_file:
    database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in database:
        print(row)
```

the following does not.

```
import csv
import sys

database = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], mode='r') as csv_file:
    database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

for row in database:
    print(row)
```

with error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 9, in
> <module>
>     for row in database:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 111, in __next__
>     self.fieldnames   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
>     self._fieldnames = next(self.reader) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The csv.DictReader object appears to exist but I cannot iterate over it in the 2nd snippet.
Checking various comments, they seem to say that DictReader returns an iterator - but I do not know understand if this is the reason for the error and what to change to gain access to database.
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could exhaust the interator and make `database` a list that contains all the rows: `database = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))`. if that fits in your memory you should  be fine. (`database = {}` at the beginning has no effect whatsoever; you overwrite this name lateron in the program).

Comment: Your indentation on the second snippet is wrong. You must move the `for` block one level to the right.

Comment: The `for` loop should be indented below the `with` statement as it is in the first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with open` is a context manager which closes the file when execution goes out of scope. As the file is closed you can't read from it.

Use the original indentation.

```
import csv
import sys

database = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], mode='r') as csv_file:
    database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in database:
        print(row)
```

You could also do the following:

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], mode='r') as csv_file:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

The second way will pull all the data into memory.

Comment: Your answer is more suited as a comment. Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @accdias - This is the answer. Keri explains the context, the reason for the error and ways to fix it. From your link _Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that_. The boxes are ticked.

Comment: My answer was originally a bit lacking. Thanks for getting me to improve it.

Comment: Thanks very much Keri! This is clear and very helpful. I've just started with python and being able to get such elaborate answers to questions so quickly is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

While getting csv file in API (Django) you can do something like this

```
import csv
import io
csv_file = request.FILES.get('csv_file')
file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(file))
for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
```